# how to make the sound effect play when page changes

Tags: javascript

the code below plays the sound when the destination to a new page in the a tags is not given. However I would like to have the sound effect play when the destination is put in as well. how can this be achieved?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav#nav1{ margin-top: 24px; }
nav#nav1 > a{ background:#B9E1FF; color:#000; padding:10px; text- 
decoration:none; border-radius:5px; font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, 
sans-serif; }
nav#nav1 > a:hover{ background: #BBEA00; }
nav#nav1 > a:active{ background: #EEFFA8; }
</style>
<script>
var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.src = 'bleep.mp3';
</script>
</head>
<body>
<nav id="nav1">
<a href="file2.html" onmousedown="bleep.play()">page1</a>
<a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">page2</a>
<a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Services</a>
<a href="#" onmousedown="bleep.play()">Contact</a>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot play the sound if another page if loaded. As soon as the "file2.html" link is clicked, the browser leaves this page, before playing any soon. It would work only for internal links (like href="#id").

Answer (score 0):

Something like this - redirect when the sound has finished

```js
var currentLink = "";
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.getElementById("nav1").addEventListener("click",
    (e) => {
      console.log(e.target.tagName)
      if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == "A") {
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel link
        curreLink = e.target.href;
        bleep.play();
      }
    });
});

var bleep = new Audio();
bleep.addEventListener("ended", () => {
  location = currentLink;
});
bleep.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-sound/3.0.7/sounds/door_bell.mp3';
```

```css
nav#nav1 {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

nav#nav1>a {
  background: #B9E1FF;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text- decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
}

nav#nav1>a:hover {
  background: #BBEA00;
}

nav#nav1>a:active {
  background: #EEFFA8;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav1">
  <a href="file2.html">page1</a>
  <a href="#">page2</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could

- block the page change on link click (using "stoppropagation" in click event handler)
- play the sound and watch for the "complete" event  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio)
- when "complete" event is triggered, then fire the page change using "document.location"